# What is a good tutorial on how to set up tomcat with mysql and database pooling?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

I have been looking for some good instructions on how to utilize connection pooling in Tomcat 6 connecting to Mysql 5, but there does not seem to be any complete references. I am having trouble piecing together different tutorials to get a clear picture.

I must admit, I am very much a beginner in dealing with Tomcat and it's configurations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the MySQL driver jar file in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/

Make a META_INF/context.xml file in your webapp (The META_INF/ folder is at the same level as your WEB_INF/ folder) that looks e.g. like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/tomcattest" docBase="tomcattest" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       maxActive="10" maxIdle="5" 
       username="mysqluser" password="mysqlpasswd"
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
       url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.30:3306/databasename?autoReconnect=true" />
 </Context>
```

You probably have to replace  path="/tomcattest" docBase="tomcattest" to match your webapp too.

You need to add a bit to your WEB_INF/web.xml too - the *resource-ref* section shown below. It might e.g. look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>tomcattest</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Now your servlets can fetch Connections from the pool by doing:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds   = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
//use conn
conn.close();
```

More info [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The only thing I would add, is that the Database (usually mysql) driver needs to be placed somewhere in the server's classpath. In eclipse, this became troublesome for me because it needed to be changed in the Server Launch Configuration, and there was a Classpath to be modified there.